# matplotlib subplot2grid axis no longer turning off in v3.8

Tags: python, matplotlib

Up until matplotlib v3.7.0 I could turn off an axis that I created using `plt.subplot2grid()`. It seems that this functionality no longer works in matplotlib v.3.8. Instead when I call `ax.axis('off')` the subplot2grid axis disappears and the original subplots return. I would like to be able to turn off the axis created using subplot2grid. Note that I have tried `ax.set_axis_off()` and this also did not work.

Does anyone know why this behavior is now occurring or if there might be a workaround to turning off the subplot2grid?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0,0] = plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(0,0),rowspan=2) # Combining the first column into a single subplot
ax[0,0].axis('off') # Note that the subplot is not turning off in matplotlib v3.8
```

I expected the subplot2grid axis to turn off as it has in matplotlib v3.7 and earlier. Instead the original axes return.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here is a tip for editing your post: if you select your code sample and hit the `{}` button at the top of the edit window, it will show as formatted code.  If you also add the `python` tag, you will get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

If I run your code with Matplotlib v3.7.1 I get this warning:

`MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Auto-removal of overlapping axes is deprecated since 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later; explicitly call ax.remove() as needed.`

So it is expected that your original two left-hand axes are no longer being automatically removed when you add the 2-row one on top of them.
Note that the `axis("off")` behaviour is unchanged in v3.8: in both versions you make that axes invisible but now the original axes are still behind it.

You could call `ax.remove()` on the original two as the warning says, or you could get the layout you want directly using [`subplot_mosaic`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/mosaic.html):

```
fig, ax_dict = plt.subplot_mosaic("AB;AC")
ax_dict["A"].axis("off")

plt.show()
```